# Ошибка error CS0103: The name 'Advertisements' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity3d

При попытке написать строку: Advertisements.Initialize("???????", false); возникает ошибка The name 'Advertisements' does not exist in the current context. ID указан верно, вызывается в void start. Реклама отображается, и даже в консоли в самом юнити при старте пишется строка UnityAdsEditor: Initialize(??????, False); где id указан верно, судя по всему он самостоятельно его подтягивает. Но я не уверен, что без этой строки я смогу получать прибыль, всё-таки дело серьёзное, а проверить пока не наступишь на грабли возможности нет. Поэтому подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку, и критична ли она, или можно оставить как есть?

Если не ошибаюсь, несколько месяцев назад, сталкивался с такой проблемой, тогда помогло полное удаление ABS и повторная установка, но помогло это на пару запуском юнити, после всё снова сломалось

Comment: Естественно, что, если закомментировать эту строку, то всё собирается и работает и дело совершенно не в правильности или неправильности ID. Эта ошибка означает, что компилятор не может найти идентификатор Advertisements, посмотрите все ли необходимые пространства имён у Вас импортированы?

Comment: Не знаю как это сделать и какие должны быть) Но сама реклама показывается

Comment: Если добавить в самое начало вот такую строку «using UnityEngine.Advertisements;», без кавычек, естественно, что-то поменяется?